# Why is setTimeout so fickle and semi-functional?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

```
function load_result()
{
    $.getJSON( "http://somesite.com/loadresult.php", function(data) {
        if( data == undefined || data == null )
        {
            console.log( "no data" );
            clearTimeout( lr_timeout );
            lr_timeout = setTimeout( "load_result()", 2000 );
            return;
        }
        insert_result_price( data );
        clearTimeout( lr_timeout );
        lr_timeout = setTimeout( "load_result()", 50 * ( Math.random() * 10 ) );

    } );
}
```

and `lr_timeout` is defined globally and the `load_result` function is kicked off initially in the `document.ready` function. The problem is that the function doesn't always run. I'll watch it in Firebug and I have another function that's set on a setInterval that always works.

Ideas?

Comment: somewhat unrelated: string arguments to `setTimeout()` are evil[tm]; in this case, just pass the function reference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your other `setTimeout` function (the one that always works) also inside a `$.getJSON`? If so, does it call it on the same URL (`http://somesite.com/loadresult.php` in your example, but I'm sure it's different in real life)?

It's possible that `http://somesite.com/loadresult.php` is a flaky resource, and your inconsistent results are due to that resource, not `setTimeout`. Of course, if they're both using that same resource, then that couldn't be the problem.

Comment: That's a setInterval actually, and it's not related to the loadresult resource.

Comment: But like jboxer said, did you check if it's a flaky source? The setTimeout in your code never gets called if data is null or undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I have never experienced a problem with setTimeout generally, and I've used it for a main/infinite loop in JS quite a few times without it ever having an issue. I would imagine that clearTimeout from one invocation of load_results is stepping on setTimeout from another, especially since it's in response to a GET request that may take longer than it takes the browser to get around to the next setTimeout.  There actually are multiple threads going on here, you just have no control over them and there is no synchronization mechanism available.

Comment: Well.. wouldn't it wait for the response from the GET since it's in the callback?

Comment: That's true, they really should go sequentially.  I guess my only suggestion is, get rid of clearTimeout and see if it makes a difference.